# What is the value of an empty time input element

Tags: php, html

I need to check if a time element is not filled in by the user. I tried to check if my element was null or has the value “—-:—“, but it doesn’t seem to work. What is the value of an empty time input field?

Comment: Why not just create a form with only a time element, submit it, and have PHP output the value (using `var_dump()`)? This is pretty basic troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time element has no default value and is handled by the browser. I suggest you do a simple test using `var_dump()` and check what is getting to the server (if there is anything getting there), or use php `empty()` function to handle almost any "false" value.